# Sticky header in ListView and GridView WinRT xaml

Tags: xaml, header, windows-runtime, scrollviewer

How could one accomplish behavior in which a header of a ListView or GridView group doesn't scroll with the content, but stays fixed until the content comes to an end and the following header then comes in focus.

The behavior can be observed in Finance app on Windows 8 Release Preview when you scroll through GridView items.

I am not expecting the whole code, but I'd like to hear some ideas, links, code snippets, samples etc. which would help me get started.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to embed a listview in a datatemplate of the main listview. Then you can embed a gridview and gridviewcolumns in the templated listviews and get your column headers that way.

Comment: Thanks but the column headers are there. I am looking for a smooth transition that is shown in Bing Finance app on Windows 8 Release Preview

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the ListView in a ScrollViewer. The ListView's internal SrollViewer won't be used, and you'll have control of the outer ScrollViewer, which will allow you to set its `TopHeader`.

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ScrollViewer.TopHeader>
        ... Your header content here ...
    </ScrollViewer.TopHeader>
    <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        ... Your body content here ...
    </ListView>
</ScrollViewer>
```